# Restful Web service- adding List of Pojos

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I am trying to pass List of Pojo's(State class) through Restful web services.

```
@POST
@Path("/saveDetails2")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String saveFormerWithLandDetails(@FormParam("name") String name, @FormParam("mobileNo") Long mobileNo,
        @FormParam("address1") String address1,@FormParam("address2") String address2,@FormParam("states")List<State> states) {
    // Business logic
    return  "SUCCESS";

}
```

In postman, below json data added as raw data:

```
{  
   "name":"ABCDSSS",
   "mobile":123456789,
   "addressLine1":"ADDRESS3456",
   "addressLine2":"ADDRESS3456",
   "states":[  
         {  
          "code":"ABC",
          "name":"TEST"
         }
    ]
 }
```

In Header, Content-Type - application/json

State table is:

```
   @XmlRootElement(name = "State")
   @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
  public class State implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @XmlElement(name = "id")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private long id;

  @XmlElement(name="code")
  @ Column(name = "state_code")
  private String code;

  @XmlElement(name="name")
  @Column(name="state_name")
  private String name;

  // setters and getters
}
```

Error is:

## HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: The @FormParam is utilized when the content type of the request entity is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded

then what is Param annotation (@QueryParam and @PathParam both are not passing data) I can use in my case?

What is the best way to use Pojo's in Restful web services and test through POSTMAN.

I found similar to this in SOF but passing List of String, I followed same approach but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@PathParam` that should extract values from the POST request.

Take a look at this https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2225

Answer (score 0):

You have included the cause to your problem in your very question.

> In Header, Content-Type - application/json

@FormParam is a parameter within a x-www-url-encoded body with the registered content-type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

The use of application/json precludes the use of @FormParam.  You have a few options: you can use the appropriate media type to leverage the annotation; you can write your own binder using AoP to parse the value and pass it; you can leverage any number of json parsing frameworks to parse it yourself; or you can use [JsonPath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath).